# How to write combination in perl?

Tags: perl, combinations

If i give a value of `3`, it should generate the combination of

```
1,2,3
1,3,2
2,3,1
2,1,3
3,1,2
3,2,1
```

Likewise it should generate combinations for any numbers.

Answer (score 3):

use: [Algorithm::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Algorithm%3a%3aCombinatorics).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);

my $nums = [qw(1 2 3)];
my $iter = combinations($nums, scalar(@{$nums}));

while (my $c = $iter->next) {
    print "@$c\n";
}
```

Comment: What he really wants is permutations, not combinations.  (Same module will work for that, just different function)